# Call static init method that needs a bean on Spring startup, without exposing another bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, startup

Hello I have the task to call the some initialization code that needs a bean (`config`) **without exposing another bean** that would do the initialization. So far I failed to accomplish that without an initializer bean.

**use case**: The `CarFactory` has a static `ìnit` method that has a `PartProvider` as parameter and should be called after the a `PartProvider`bean is available.  `CarFactory` and `SeatProvider` are from a dependencies and cannot be changed.

```java
import javax.inject.Inject;

public abstract class CarFactory {

    private static PartProvider partProvider;

    private CarFactory() {
    }

    @Inject
    public static void init(final PartProvider partProvider) {
        PartProvider.partProvider = partProvider;
    }
}
```

```java
public class SeatProvider implements PartProvider {

    Config config;

    @Inject
    public SeatProvider(@NonNull Config config) {
        this.config = config;
   }

}
```

My current code that exposes the initializer bean

**initalizer bean**

```java
public class FactoryInitializer implements InitializingBean {

    private PartProvider partProvider

    @Inject
    public FactoryInitializer(PartProvider partProvider) {
        this.partProvider = partProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        CarFactory.init(provider);
    }
}
```

**configuration**

```java
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FactoryInitializer factoryInitializer(final Config config) {
        return new FactoryInitializer(new SeatProvider(config));
    }
}
```

---

This an ugly but working 'hack'. That produces an `Object` bean that is `null`.

```java
@Bean
public Object notificationInit(final Config config) {
    CarFactory.init(new SeatProvider(config));
    return null;
}
```

---

What I really need to do is call the following code, at a place where the `config` is available.

```java
CarFactory.init(new SeatProvider(config));
```

Comment: If the `Config` is a bean, you can use `@PostConstruct` method inside it and call it like `CarFactory.init(new SeatProvider(this));`, however I am not sure about this.

Comment: `this.partProvider = partProvider;` won't compile inside a static method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solved my problem as @michalk suggested. The configuration is a bean itself that I need anyways. It gets the config injected and runs the initialization code in its `@PostConstruct init()` method.

So the config is available as a bean and there is no need for an initializer class.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfiguration {

    @Inject
    private Config config;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        CarFactory.init(new SeatProvider(config));
    }
}
```